# Multi-Parameter Sub-Classes in Idris

Tags: idris

Inspired by [this blog post](http://sitr.us/2014/05/05/category-theory-proofs-in-idris.html) and [this code](https://github.com/TimRichter/CId/blob/master/Category.lidr) I thought I'd try some category theory in Idris using its interfaces (type-classes).

I defined `Category` as follows, which works fine:

```
interface Category (obj : Type) (hom : obj -> obj -> Type) where
  id : {a : obj} -> hom a a
  comp : {a, b, c : obj} -> hom b c -> hom a b -> hom a c
```

Then, in the spirit of the [`Verified`](https://github.com/idris-lang/Idris-dev/blob/master/libs/contrib/Classes/Verified.idr) module, I thought I'd define a verified category:

```
interface Category obj hom =>
          VerifiedCategory (obj : Type) (hom : obj -> obj -> Type) where
  categoryAssociativity : {a, b, c, d : obj} ->
                          (f : hom c d) -> (g : hom b c) -> (h : hom a b) ->
                          (comp (comp f g) h = comp f (comp g h))
  categoryLeftIdentity : {a, b : obj} -> (f : hom a b) -> (comp id f = f)
  categoryRightIdentity : {a, b : obj} -> (f : hom a b) -> (comp f id = f)
```

Unfortunately, Idris rejects that code with the following error message:

```
When checking type of constructor of CategoryTheory.VerifiedCategory:
Can't find implementation for Category obj hom
```

Am I doing something wrong, or am I trying to do something with multi-parameter sub-classes that Idris cannot do?

All this code is in its own module, called `CategoryTheory`, without any imports.

I'm working with Idris v0.12.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know why (and would be very curious to find out!) but it works if you specify all the implicit arguments to `id` and `comp` in `VerifiedCategory` explicitly. It is pretty ugly and tedious to figure out, but this typechecks:

```
interface Category obj hom => VerifiedCategory (obj : Type) (hom : obj -> obj -> Type) where
  categoryAssociativity : {a, b, c, d : obj} ->
                          (f : hom c d) ->
                          (g : hom b c) ->
                          (h : hom a b) ->
                          (comp {a = a} {b = b} {c = d} (comp {a = b} {b = c} {c = d} f g) h = comp {a = a} {b = c} {c = d} f (comp {a = a} {b = b} {c = c} g h))
  categoryLeftIdentity : {a, b : obj} ->
                         (f : hom a b) ->
                         (comp {a = a} {b = b} {c = b} (id {a = b}) f = f)
  categoryRightIdentity : {a, b : obj} ->
                          (f : hom a b) ->
                          (comp {a = a} {b = a} {c = b} f (id {a = a}) = f)
```

**Edit**: Another way I just found is to explicitly designate `hom` as a [determining parameter](http://docs.idris-lang.org/en/latest/tutorial/interfaces.html#determining-parameters), i.e. the parameter of the type class that is sufficient to find an implementation. This has to happen in `Category` as well as in `VerifiedCategory` (I'm not sure, why), like so:

```
interface Category (obj : Type) (hom : obj -> obj -> Type) | hom where
-- ...

interface Category obj hom => VerifiedCategory (obj : Type) (hom : obj -> obj -> Type) where
-- ...
```

i.e. by putting a `| hom` before the `where`.

One thing you have to do in addition to that is qualify the usage of `id` in `VerifiedCategory`, because otherwise it is interpreted as implicit parameter for whatever reason:

```
  categoryLeftIdentity : {a, b : obj} ->
                         (f : hom a b) ->
                         comp CategoryTheory.id f = f
  categoryRightIdentity : {a, b : obj} ->
                          (f : hom a b) ->
                          comp f CategoryTheory.id = f
```

See also [this](https://redd.it/4q7znu) reddit thread that might be illuminating in the future.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Thanks, your edit worked out for me. When designating `hom` as a determining parameter I can actually drop all explicit specifications of implicit arguments and it works.